# Simulation of VHDL file on Quartus 13

Tags: simulation, vhdl, fpga, intel-fpga

Over past days the option "Run Functional Simulation" (in waveform part) in Altera Quartus 13 here (i use in Ubuntu 11.10) was working fine, but since yesterday It, all of sudden, is not working. When I click in the option, it's opened a tiny grey retangle, and so it disappears. In other words, simulation doesn't work. Does anyone knows how to solve this problem?

Best Regards,
Inácio.

Comment: This is an OS, environment issue, I am not sure if anyone can help you, unless if they have had an exact same type of problem themselves.

Answer (score 0):

I recommend to start quartus in a console do exactly what you have done before and paste at least everything what is outputs in the console. Otherwise nobody can really help you.

My crystal ball tells me that you could delete or update a library which the simulator needs, or the `PATH` variable does not include the path of the executable of the simulator.